# GCD crashes with any task longer than 255 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

The following code produces a crash in the iOS simulator.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSDate *sleepStart = [NSDate date];
        while ([sleepStart timeIntervalSinceNow] > -300) {

        }
    });    
}
```

**Update: This issue occurs even on the background thread**.

The code below is also buggy:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSDate *sleepStart = [NSDate date];
        while ([sleepStart timeIntervalSinceNow] > -300) {

        }
    });    
}
```

That's all.  Paste that into any view controller, run the app in the simulator for exactly four minutes and 15 seconds, and it will crash.

The crash is a type I have never seen before.  It's "EXC_??? (11)".  Oddly, you can press the Continue button after the crash, and it will go on just as normal.

Why is this crashing?  How can I submit long tasks to a queue without causing this behavior?

Here are some things I have tried so far, that have shed no light whatsoever on the mystery:

- Creating my **own dispatch queues** (including ones on background threads)
- Using NSBlockOperation instead of GCD (still crashes)
- Inserting sleeps.  Short sleeps (under 5 seconds or so) seem to delay the crash by the time of the sleep.  Longer sleeps seem to do a lot more.  So if you sleep once for five seconds, it will crash at 4m 20s instead of 4m 15s.  If you sleep once for 60 seconds, it takes about ten minutes to crash, but it happens eventually.  This clue seems significant, but I have no idea what it could mean.

**update #1**

The issue only reproduces under LLDB, not GDB.

Comment: You held up the MAIN THREAD? Yes, it's going to crash.

Comment: To expand on that: iOS sees that your app has been unresponsive (not responding to any events) for a ridiculous amount of time, and since that means your app is broken, it kills your app. You shouldn't hold up the main queue for much more than 1/60th of a second, let alone 4 minutes. Why don't you run this block in one of the concurrent queues?

Comment: Question updated, the behavior is independent of whether the main queue is blocked or a background queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an [Apple engineer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/790874#790874):

> The "crash" you are seeing isn't really a crash, its a log when an
>   application uses too much CPU time for a sustained period of time. Its
>   reason to exist is to tell you not to do that, and where the CPU time
>   is being spent.   In production the logs are simply logged and your
>   process should continue. But if you can avoid these types of logs,
>   that would be better.

And later:

> You should file a bug report. lldb should be smart enough to ignore that trap by default.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot perform lengthy operations on the main thread. You should dispatch your block to another thread, then at the end of the block dispatch back to the main thread (if you need to).

Using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{});` causes your operation to be performed (blocking) on the main thread in the near future.

The main thread is protected by a timer; if you stop responding to events, iOS will kill it. This is intentional: Don't do heavy lifting on the main thread!

iOS's tolerance is usually *much less* than four minutes, but it gets longer  if you're debugging. The simulator has its own rules.

On startup, it's a matter of seconds. But you shouldn't do anything taking more than a split second on the main thread, and only then in response to a direct user action (such as the user tapping something). Doing work on the main thread causes the iOS UI to become less responsive, jerky instead of glass-smooth.

If your app stop responding to events on the main thread on OSX, it beachballs. Your app stops responding to events on the main thread on iOS, the iOS watchdog takes it out back and shoots it.

From [TechNote TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html):

> The exception code 0x8badf00d indicates that an application has been terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events. One common cause of this is doing synchronous networking on the main thread. Whatever operation is on Thread 0: needs to be moved to a background thread, or processed differently, so that it does not block the main thread.

Generally, the pattern is:

```
- (IBAction)tappedWhatever:(id)sender {
    // visually start operation
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
        // do work here, off main thread
        // (you can't update the UI here)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            // show progress in UI
        });
        // more heavy lifting
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            // update UI to show operation complete and move to next step
        });
    });
};
```

(I could have sworn there was a better description of this in Apple's docs, but I can't find it now. Anyone?)

Comment: Interesting...is "beachballs" the official term xD?  I always referred to it as "the candy wheel of death"

Comment: I always liked spinning pizza, but beachballs seems to have won out. :)

Comment: "I'm surprised the timeout is set this long" - Maybe because he's trying it in the Simulator? On a device, the Watchdog should kill him in 10 seconds.

Comment: Is the simulator's timeout that much longer? Wow. I know launching with the debugger also lengthens the timeout.

Comment: Simulator or device regardless, if I hang up the main thread on a *debug build* while the debugger is running, the watchdog will yell at me but it won't kill the app (well, maybe it will after 255 seconds?).  Instead I just get a log message telling me that my main thread was not responding (this happens sometimes when I pause the debugger too).

Comment: I think it's supposed to be 240 seconds (4 minutes).

Comment: This answer can easily be verified.  However, the same behavior occurs even on the background thread, eliminating the watchdog from being a possible cause.