# Strange crash on glDrawElements [ EXC_??? (11)(code = 0, subcode=0x0) ]

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

my app runs just fine, but after about 3 minutes i get a strange crash that looks like this

[image]
[image]

has anyone experienced something like this before and know what could be the cause? could this be some kind of memory leak?

some code:

```
- (void) draw {
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);
shader.modelViewMatrix = mvm;
[shader texture:texture];
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}

- (void) texture: (int) tex {

glUseProgram(TextureShader);
_camModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(_cameraMatrix, _modelViewMatrix);
_modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(_projectionMatrix, _camModelViewMatrix);
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp, 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[tex]);
}
```

if you need to see any other code let me know

Comment: ok it seems to only be a problem with the simulator, running it on the device has lasted for 10min now, will keep testing

Comment: Is there any chance that you could be accessing accessing your OpenGL ES context from more than one thread? If so, that can cause a crash like this (which may only show up on your multi-core Mac and multi-core iOS devices, not a single-core iOS device).

Comment: nope, all is done on the main thread. but dont worry, this was only a simulator issue it seems, i left the program running on my ipad2 (which is dual core) for over an hour and there was no crash, so i think its safe to assume it wont happen

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found good documentation on the EXC_??? exception, but my understanding is that the thread has been consuming CPU for too long. The best explanation of this problem I've found is in another question on stackoverflow: [GCD crashes with any task longer than 255 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194163/gcd-crashes-with-any-task-longer-than-255-seconds). I have had this problem when writing long testcases, and I fixed them by breaking them up into smaller testcases or improving the performance of the testcase with the EXC_???. It's worth it to take a look at the stack when the EXC_??? happens and consider whether improvements could be made to speed up the path.